# inferred type is String but Int was expected

Tags: kotlin

a new Kotlin learner Trying understand basics and been trying to add integers from a console input variable to a mutablelist but i get the error (Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Int was expected). I seem not to tell where the issue is.

```
fun main() {

    val amount = mutableListOf<Int>()           //Mutable list to store the Ints

    println("Add an amount to the list: ")

    val money = readLine()!!.toInt()            //Requesting for an IntInput

    amount.add(6000)                            //Adding Ints to the list

    amount.add(8000)                            //Adding Ints to the list

    amount.add("$money")                        **LINE WITH THE ERROR IS THIS ONE WHEN PASSING THE MONEY VARIBALE THAT HOLDING THE INT INPUT** 

    println("$amount")                          //Printing the list items
}
```

Comment: `amount.add("$money")` is equivalent to `amount.add(money.toString())`. But `amount` is a `MutableList<Int>` (a mutable list of `Int`s), so you can't add a `String` to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"$money"` creates a string that contains the value of `money`. You need to use `money` directly:

```
amount.add(money)
```

Comment: Mmm.  The same applies to `println("$amount")` too, of course; that would be more natural as `println(amount)` (unless you needed to append a full stop or something).

Comment: Thank you. Really helpful.